# Bundle only the main component with Svelte

Tags: webpack, rollup, svelte

I would like to bundle only the main component in a Svelte application and bootstrap the application myself in a script tag with the container of my choice.

In the Svelte template (rollup and bootstrap), the application is bootstrap in the main.js, which import the App.svelte. I would like bundle only the App.svelte and instanciate the App class myself. The objective is to be able to reuse the app in whatever plateform I want and be able to choose the target (ex: use a component in a CMS, SharePoint, etc.).

So do :

```
const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {}
});
```

myself in a script tag in the index.html

I am novice to webpack and I can't find how to bundle and then call the App class in the index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found what I wanted with the sveltejs/template start project, which use rollup.

In the main.js, delete the instantiation of App class and export that class.

```
import App from './App.svelte';

export default App;
```

The rollup build will store the default export of main.js in a variable, named in the rollup.config file ( output -> name ), app by default.

Edit the index.html, deplace the script in the body, and then add a script tag :

```
<body>
    <div id="app-container"></div>
    <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
    <script>
        var myapp= new app({
            "target": document.getElementById("app-container"),
            "props": {
                "name": 'world'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I removed the defer attribute of the bundle script tag to be sure it is run before.

**EDIT - WEBPACK CONFIG**

I finally found how to do with webpack, the ouput must be set as a library and the export must be the default (or you must instanciate with new app.default({...}) )

The webpack config edited from the svelte template :

```
entry: './src/App.svelte',
resolve: {
    alias: {
        svelte: path.resolve('node_modules', 'svelte')
    },
    extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.svelte'],
    mainFields: ['svelte', 'browser', 'module', 'main']
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'bundle.[id].js',
    library: 'app',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiences. Btw if you are babel-ing in your webpack you may be able to `export { default } from './src/App.svelte'`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [compile options](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_compile) of Svelte, you will notice that there's an option to compile as a web component, **customElement**. This is what you are looking for, along with the **tag** options.

Comment: Do you mean "customElement" ?

Comment: I see but that doesnt explain how to configure webpack or rollup, can you show me a config example ? Should I set the app.svelte as entry point ? How can I get the exported class in a script tag in index.html ?

Comment: @2pha you are right, I updated with the exact option name.
@PortePoisse If you are using rollup, you should have a plugin named `svelte` you can add the options to. The App.svelte component will be your custom element. You can find a more detailled guide [here](https://medium.com/@dudousxd/svelte-your-way-ad50f9455553)